# I'm having trouble working on 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm super new to python programming and I'm pursuing an MBA in data science and machine learning. I'm stuck on a problem that I can't solve, I have these 2 tables in CSV, one with some data on purchases of public papers here in my country, and the other is the interest rate of each month of the years that I managed to get.

What I would like to do is pass the value of these fees to the transaction dataframe grouped by month, I'm really not able to do that, if anyone can help me on how to do this I will be grateful.

I put the 2 csv in the drive for anyone:
[2 csv files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18_sOSIZZw9DCW7ftEKuOG4aIzGXoasFe?usp=sharing)

Some code I managed to do to clean the data frames:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('VendasTesouroDireto3.csv', sep=';')
df['Data Venda'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data Venda'])
df.sort_values(by='Data Venda', ascending=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv('historico.csv', sep = ';')
df2['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Data'])
df2.dropna()
```

Just to contextualize: I want to pass the values of the column "Taxa Selic (ao ano)" of the table "historico", to the table "VendasTesouroDireto3" grouped by months and year.

This topic will be made public once posted.

Comment: your files are not accessible... `permission` required, check your shared link options

Comment: I think I left the drive link closed, follow it again with it open: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18_sOSIZZw9DCW7ftEKuOG4aIzGXoasFe?usp=sharing

Comment: works now, t.y.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# reading in the Data
histdf = pd.read_csv(r'c:\temp\historico.csv', sep=';')
vendasdf = pd.read_csv(r'c:\temp\VendasTesouroDireto3.csv',sep=';')

# Change the dates to datetime format 
histdf['Data2'] = histdf['Data'].astype('datetime64')
vendasdf['Data Venda2'] = pd.to_datetime(vendasdf['Data Venda'], format= '%d/%m/%Y')

# merging the two DF based on the date
vendasdf.merge(histdf, left_on='Data Venda2', right_on='Data2', how='left')
```

```
    Tipo Titulo     Vencimento do Titulo    Data Venda  PU  Quantidade  Valor   Data Venda2     Data    Taxa Selic (ao ano)     Data2
368     Tesouro IPCA+ com Juros Semestrais  15/08/2020  28/04/2010  1.867568e+09    99.40   185636.21   2010-04-28  28/04/10    0.095   2010-04-28
369     Tesouro Prefixado com Juros Semestrais  01/01/2017  28/04/2010  9.155121e+08    169.80  155453.95   2010-04-28  28/04/10    0.095   2010-04-28
370     Tesouro IPCA+ com Juros Semestrais  15/05/2045  28/04/2010  1.903001e+09    278.20  529414.83   2010-04-28  28/04/10    0.095   2010-04-28
371     Tesouro Selic   07/03/2015  28/04/2010  4.204119e+09    12.60   52971.89    2010-04-28  28/04/10    0.095   2010-04-28
372     Tesouro Prefixado   01/01/2012  28/04/2010  8.235668e+08    699.40  576002.63   2010-04-28  28/04/10    0.095   2010-04-28
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: It helped me a lot, but I have a question. why import datetime? I was able to change the dates that were as object in date time too, but then I couldn't work with them or replace them to Month for example, did I really need to import this datetime?

Comment: hi @GabrielRodrigues, you don't need to import datetime, and pd.to_datetime works just as fine. to get the month or year. use dt.month or dt.year. for example vendasdf['Data Venda2'].dt.month or vendasdf['Data Venda2'].dt.year